# after using restoreState, markup position is random wrong

Tags: autodesk-viewer

We are using restoreState to restore the original state to show the markups.
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/viewerstate/
After i rotated the BIM 3D model, then i call restoreState to restore the original state.
restore state bring back to the original state. But then i called markup.loadMarkups();
The markup data and state is always correct.
Sometimes the markup position is wrong. This is random.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick sample showing how a viewer state and markup state can be restored: https://forge-hello-world-v3.herokuapp.com/tests/restore-state.html.

Note that the Forge Viewer version 2.* is significantly out-dated (the current version is 7.*). In order for us to be able to support you better, please consider upgrading your code.